# Application breaks in production build

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

for about 2 years I created a Ticket at "Sencha Support", where I explained and showed a bug which breaks my whole application.

So I reopened this ticket and asked if there is any solution, because we want to publish our application and need this production-build...

The answer was "Please note that there is no timeline for issue resolution, at this time...." ..but you can pay more money.. after you waited 2 years.. payed for our software and support.. even if it's a bug..

So i would like to ask the community to help me out whith this..

If you create the following with ExtJS V6.5.3 -> 7.2.1, modern Toolkit AND you have to use SenchaCmd/ SenchaArchitect to make a production-build!

```
Ext.define('Test.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'Ext.layout.Fit'
    ],
    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: 'main',
    defaults: {
        tab: {
            iconAlign: 'top'
        }
    },
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBar: {
        layout: {
            type: 'box',
            pack: 'start',
            overflow: 'scroller'
        }
    },
    items: [
        // TODO - Replace the content of this view to suit the needs of your application.
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home',
            layout: 'fit',
            // The following grid shares a store with the classic version's grid as well!
            items: [{
                xtype: 'mainlist'
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'Users',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-user',
            bind: {
                html: '{loremIpsum}'
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Groups',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-users',
            bind: {
                html: '{loremIpsum}'
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Settings',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-cog',
            bind: {
                html: '{loremIpsum}'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

After you build you will see an error like this:

```
app.js?_dc=1599337408898:46636 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
    at constructor.applyOverflow (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:46636)
    at constructor.setter [as setOverflow] (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:5728)
    at Ext.Configurator.configure (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6036)
    at constructor.initConfig (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6675)
    at constructor (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:10235)
    at constructor (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:37826)
    at constructor.callParent (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6650)
    at constructor (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:46423)
    at new Ext.layout.Box (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6978)
    at Ext.Factory.create (app.js?_dc=1599337408898:11479)
applyOverflow   @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:46636
setter  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:5728
configure   @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6036
initConfig  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6675
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:10235
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:37826
callParent  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6650
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:46423
Ext.layout.Box  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6978
create  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:11479
fn  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:11577
applyLayout @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:37072
setter  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:5728
configure   @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6036
initConfig  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6675
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:10235
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:20866
callParent  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6650
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:24330
callParent  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6650
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:36941
callParent  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6650
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:46669
Ext.tab.Bar @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6978
eval    @   VM95:3
create  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:7870
factory @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:5196
applyTabBar @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:49637
setter  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:5728
(anonymous) @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:5719
updateTabBarPosition    @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:49660
setter  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:5732
configure   @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6047
initConfig  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6675
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:10235
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:20866
callParent  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6650
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:24330
callParent  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6650
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:36941
tabtest.view.MyTabPanel @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6978
eval    @   VM95:3
create  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:7870
launch  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:50015
onBeforeLaunch  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:36111
onProfilesReady @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:36065
constructor @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:36045
tabtest.$application    @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:6978
(anonymous) @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:36227
invoke  @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:8964
doInvokeAll @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:8989
invokeAll   @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:8971
handleReady @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:8945
(anonymous) @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:8953
elevate @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:2426
timerFn @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:4115
setTimeout (async)      
defer   @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:4117
handleReadySoon @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:8951
fireReady   @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:8936
doReadyEvent    @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:9027
onReadyEvent    @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:9015
bind    @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:8906
(anonymous) @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:9114
(anonymous) @   app.js?_dc=1599337408898:9115
```

Comment: Did you tried to build `testing` before?

Comment: Can you post the entire log? By the way... the sencha support is terrible!

Comment: I edited my post to show the whole log

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [`Ext.tab.Bar`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tab.Bar.html):

> TabBar is used internally by a Ext.tab.Panel and typically should not need to be created manually.

... it doesn't even have a `layout` config - and there is no layout `box` either; only `hbox` & `vbox`.

Comment: I changed it to hbox, but it doesn't fix it

Comment: There is no `layout` config; so why are you trying to configure one?

Comment: In the docs I found this: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.tab.Bar.html#cfg-layout

I need it to force a leftsided arrangement instead of a centered.

Like I mentioned before if I just publish it it all works fine, so there must be a difference between the build & the publish version

Comment: It tries to bind that `overflow: 'scroller'` ...but there is no `update()` method. The `layout` is merely defined by `docked` configuration. Your example does not suffice to reproduce anytihing.

Comment: What would a sufficient example look like, maybe I can somehow provide an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to require the new layout.

```
classic
    requires: [..., 'Ext.layout.container.Box']
modern
    requires: [..., 'Ext.layout.Box']
```

Usually if something works in dev and not in production, you are missing a requires.
From the code you posted I cannot tell exactly how you require your viewModel and viewController.
As a first try to add the following to your Application.js inside the app folder AND remove the requires from the app.js:

```
requires: [
    'Test.*',
    'Ext.*'
],
```

This will add everything to your build application.
!!! Though I do not recommend to ship it that way. !!!

Background:
If you add a panel, then you add a ton of requires on the fly.
But additional layouts have to be required at least once in your app.

And while you are changing your code, try to use best practise

```
    viewModel: {type: 'main'},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `Ext.layout.overflow.Scroller` in your requires config:

```
requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox',
    'Ext.layout.Fit',
    'Ext.layout.overflow.Scroller'
],
```

It worked for me.